# Get Java VM pointer in global object constructor in Android native code before JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I have a global object in native code which need to call Java code in it's constructor. Normally to get `JavaVM` pointer, I get the in `JNI_OnLoad` and cache it.

But the global object constructor is get called before `JNI_OnLoad`. And since you cannot really call `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` or `JNI_CreateJavaVM` from Android native code.

Does anyone know how to get a `JavaVM` pointer before `JNI_OnLoad` get called?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, let's assume that you have **libziron.so** that has a global object with constructor that needs `JavaVM* vm`.

Build another library, **lib1.so**, which will have only

```
JavaVM* g_vm;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* /*reserved*/)
{
    g_vm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

In Java, you load **lib1.so** and after that **libziron.so**. In **libziron.so**, you can now access extern **g_vm**. Note that while **libziron.so** depends on **lib1.so**, you must load them manually, in the right order.

Comment: That does solve my issue. It's really a clever way to do it.